# Clojurescript on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, clojure, clojurescript

I love writing Clojure webapps, however they have unacceptably long startup times when used on a platform such as Heroku.  Has anybody tried using Clojurescript on the server side with Node for example?  Does this improve startup time?

Comment: Please note: switching to Clojurescript + Nodejs is a huge tradeoff: Clojure on the JVM has much better runtime performance. Also, you'll miss the mature Clojure libraries because Clojurescript versions are limited while interoping native Javascript ones is kinda ugly and fragile (from the functional programming perspective). So if you're developing serious server side application, it's not recommended to use Clojurescript + Nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bodil had an experimental Ring-inspired web server framework for ClojureScript on Node.js here:

https://github.com/bodil/dogfort

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it improves it a lot, startup is instant as with nodejs, so give it a try.

This template should get you started (and the readme has a lot of useful information):

https://github.com/quile/node-cljs-template